# Is there a way to change meters to miles in the app?

Tags: ingress

I am looking for a way to change meters to miles in the app.

Are there any settings for this?  I have been looking all through my phone and the game and see nowhere to do this.

Thank you

Comment: Google wants us to learn the metric system.

Answer (score 5):

No, there's no way to change the units of measure, it's fixed to meters. [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ingress-discuss/YpNrp3CXI3c) you can see a discussion about this on Google Groups.